Calculating maximum area between 2 curves
Find all possible values of $k$, for which area of the region bounded by the parabolas $2y^2=kx$ and $ky^2=2(y−x)$ is maximum.
My approach was first finding the point at which they meet and I got it as $y = \frac{2k}{k^2+4}$ Then I tried integrating the (1st parabola equation $-$ 2nd parabola equation) from 0 to ${2k}{k²+4}$ in terms of $dy$ but I cannot proceed further and find this very lengthy.

Your approach is correct and it is not that lengthy. Assuming $k>0$, let $p = \frac{2}{k} + \frac{k}{2}$. The equations of the parabolas can be written
\begin{equation}
x_1 = \frac{2}{k}y^2, \quad x_2 = -\frac{k}{2}y^2 + y
\end{equation}
The difference is
\begin{equation}
x_2 - x_1 = - p y^2 + y
\end{equation}
The parabolas cross when $y=0$ and $y=\frac{1}{p}$ as you found. The area between them is
\begin{equation}
A = \int_0^{1/p}(x_2 - x_1) d y = -\frac{p}{3p^3} + \frac{1}{2 p^2} = \frac{1}{6 p^2}
\end{equation}
Now can you find which $k$ maximizes $A$ ?
